# HTML5 duration time of MP3 sometimes works

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm having problems showing the duration time of an MP3 file in my HTML5 audio player. Sometimes it will load the duration time, sometimes it won't.

The times it doesn't load is when I'm making changes to the CSS and when I refresh the page.

When I change the MP3 file to load another MP3 file, the duration time shows up. It goes away when I refresh the page.

This is the code for duration time:

```
audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
  progress.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(audio.duration));
  duration.textContent  = toHHMMSS(audio.duration);
});
```

I'm new at JavaScript so I have no idea how to code. I'm using this code from https://codepen.io/davatron5000/pen/uqktG and when you refresh the page, the duration of mp3 file disappears.

Comment: the duration isn't actually meta, try the `oncanplaythrough` event; it should be correct then

Comment: @dandavis duration is in metadata...

Comment: If you are setting the src on the markup (html) and executing your script after, the cached version of your media may already be loaded when you attach the event listener. Hence your event handler won't fire ever. You can either set again the src in js, or check for duration directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of cache.

If you are setting your audio's src in the markup (html), the cached version of your media may already be loaded* when you attach the event listener.

Hence your event handler won't fire ever :

```js
window.onload = function(){ // kinda force the situation

  aud.onloadedmetadata = function(e){  // this won't fire
    console.log('metatadata loaded');
    };
  };
```

```html
<audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3" id="aud"/>
```

But in this case, you can already access its `duration`.
So you just have to check for its duration :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (aud.duration) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    aud.onloadedmetadata = doSomething;
  }
}

function doSomething(event) {
  console.log(aud.duration);
  console.log('from event handler :', !!event);
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3" id="aud" />
```

Or you can set again your media src in js.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  aud.onloadedmetadata = function doSomething(event) {
    console.log(aud.duration);
  }

  aud.src = aud.src; // forces the event to fire again
}
```

```html
<audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3" id="aud" />
```

*UAs have different behavior for this, e.g FF will store all the load events until all the inline scripts has been parsed. Safari and sometimes Chrome fire it as soon as they can.

Comment: I'm new a javascript, do I put this inside 'audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){'?

https://codepen.io/davatron5000/pen/uqktG

Comment: @GregorySchultz, In the answer I give you two different ways to handle this, here is the updated codepen with the first solution : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNYGqm For the second solution, just add `audio.src = audio.src;` at line 40 of your js.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.